# Is there a smart way to go back to first or second page in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

Something like

For example, page C has a Go Back button,

Page A -> Page B -> Page C, click it, back to page A and keep the page A do not refresh

Does router can be achieved? Thanks

Comment: What's the problem? Could you clarify your question?

Comment: like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page-in-angular-2

Comment: I mean I click one button in page a to get to page B, and then click one button in page B to  get to page C. And now I want to achieve that by click one button in Page C to back to Page A without refreshing page A

Comment: it seems that below method is not work                                                              import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';


@Component({ directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES] })
@RouteConfig([
    {...},
])
class AppCmp {
    constructor(private _location: Location) {
    }
    backClicked() {
        this._location.back();
    }
}

Comment: maybe you're missing some dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
// component's declarations here
})
class SomeComponent {
    constructor(private location: Location) {
    }
    backClicked() {
        this.location.back();
    }
}
```

This works fine!

First: Import Location as in the line 2;
Second: Inject in the constructor as in the line;
Third: Use calling `this.location.back();`, where `location` is the name declared in the constructor

source: [How to go back last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page)