# Angular2 restrict navigation to within app

Tags: javascript, angular2-routing

**What I want to achieve** is very basic here. In an Angular2 application, I have the following flow:

1. user goes to my app
2. the app shows an *input view* (`/whatever`) with inputs and all
3. user clicks on a save button
4. the app shows a *summary view* (`/summary`)

**What I need** is for the *summary view* to be **accessible only by pressing the button** on the *input view*. This means:

- the user gets redirected when on the *summary view* and reloading the page
- the user gets redirected when trying to access the *summary view* directly by typing the `/summary` url in the browser
- the user gets redirected when accessing the *summary view* from another page which is not *input view*

**What I tried** is to implement a safeGuard for the *summary view* using `canActivate`. The problem is, *I can't find a way to get the previous url !*

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
            state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
     // return previous_url == '/whatever'
     // how to find previous_url ???
}
```

Any help on how to get the previous url in a guard or another way to achieve this is welcome.

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page-in-angular-2

Comment: I am inside a _guard_, not a component. I tried the `Location`, which is useless for the previous url.

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can check the condition in the summary component like this.

previousUrlSnapshot: string;

```
constructor(router: Router) {
  router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .subscribe(e => {
    console.log('prev:', this.previousUrlSnapshot);
    this.previousUrlSnapshot = e.url;
    if(this.previousUrlSnapshot.includes('inputViewRoute')) // your Input Route
    {
       this.router.navigateByUrl("inputViewRoute");
    }
  });
}
```