# How to get the previous route in angular2, so after some processing making the navigation back to previous url

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a page with option of wishlist, now if user is not logged in and clicks the wishlist button then user is redirected login page, but after successful user login i want to take user to previous routing state where user clicked the wishlist button ??

I tried using router events like RoutesRecognized but this is not getting fired up first time if i visit the login page second time it fires up. Any suggestions than please do help.

I even used pairwise() method of router events but this also fires second time not first time, that is if i go back to page 1 and re navigate to page2, this method fires up. It simply not getting fired up on first visit from page 1 -> page 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go back last page in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To implement the most reliable way to go back to previous view in Angular you have to:

- > import { Location } from '@angular/common;
- Inject location on component constructor:

  > constructor(
  >       private _location: Location
  >   ) {}
- Call back() method on desired function:

  > public goBack() {
  >       this._location.back();
  >   }

Answer (score 1):

You can use angulars RouterStateSnapshot https://angular.io/api/router/RouterStateSnapshot.

```
import { RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

constructor(state: RouterStateSnapshot) { }

this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }
```

Comment: using this throws me error No provider for RouterStateSnapshot!! So i am using this  const snapshot: RouterStateSnapshot = router.routerState.snapshot; but this gives me only the current route state not previous. According to you where should i keep my code ??