# Go back to previous page in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I want to have back-to-the-previous page.

Previous Page: job.html
Current Page: jobDetail.html

As per instructions, I have added `import { Location } from '@angular/common';` to the `jobDetail.component.ts` file at the top followed by

```
export class MyDetailComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private location: Location) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.location.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
    }
}
```

I have a html code in jobDetail.html but don't know how to proceed further. How do I add a previous button correctly. There's no easy tutorial for newbies like me.

```
<a routerLink="">Back</a>
```

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page

Comment: Thank you. I had gone through that link earlier but couldn't get it to work. I used the solution by Hinrich and it worked.

Answer (score 21):

This worked as posted by Hinrich:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
// more imports here...

@Component({
  // component's declarations here
})
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(private location: Location) { } // inject Location into class constructor

  cancel() {
    this.location.back(); // <-- go back to previous location on cancel
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<a (click)="cancel()">Back</a>
```

Comment: this is inefficient as angular's router module has a back method

Comment: can you provide more details to your comment @mast3rd3mon?