# In Angular routing, how i can configure routing when the component is a shared one?

Tags: angular

i have a component which is used in different screens in the application. I have a back button in this shared component. As I navigate to this component from different other components, when i click Back button in shared component, i need to route back to the screen from where I routed to the shared component. 
For example:
S is my shared component to which I navigate from A, B, C and D screens/components.
Now, when I click back button in shared component, I need to go back to the component from where I routed to the shared one. 
Is there any solution to this or any idea how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go back last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page)

Comment: I have to navigate between components of different modules. and this solution is not working in this case.

Comment: Use Router.url to know in wich route you are, or a @Input in your component

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser back like so.

```
@Component({
   ...
})
class SharedComponent {
    constructor(private location: Location) {
    }
    back() {
        this.location.back();
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution is not working in my case. if I am applying this, screen is getting navigated to the module which i initially opened but not to the one from where i navigated to the shared component.