# Angular 5 - Which should I use to navigate backward - href or location.back()?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, location, href

I have an app of which one can navigate to a page in which there is no way forwards. Think of clicking a program in a TV guide to open a page with that program's details, obviously you will want to go back to the TV guide.

For a button to go backward to the TV guide, I have an `<a>` tag.

Which would be the most advisable use case for this:

1. Using `href="/guide"`

or

2. Using `(click)=goBack()` where the function calls `location.back()`

Comment: I would use the "back" method from the location service imported with: import {Location} from '@angular/common';

Comment: you can get answer from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page/41953992

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go back last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page)

Comment: Consider if the user reaches the page by another way. If they click a Google search result that goes directly to the program details page, should the back button take them to the guide page, or back to their Google search results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to navigate in an Angular app, you don't want to use classic `href` links since they are designed to work for server-rendered apps, but not client-side apps that use the [History Javascript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History).

Prefer using the [RouterLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) from Angular.

Between `RouterLink` and `location.back()` the choice is yours, it depends whether you want to control the page you want to redirect to, or just want the same behavior as the back button from your browser.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yeah, `RouterLink` had cropped into my brain, just a case of what somebody had left in the code before I looked at it. I think I may use the `RouterLink` method as `location.back()` didn't appear to be any faster, and it's more legible from the HTML

Answer (score 3):

You should use built-in Location service of Angular as.

[Angular-Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#back)

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';


@Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

class AppComponent {
    constructor(private location: Location) {
    }
    back() {
        this.location.back();
    }
}
```