# How to go back in Ionic 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

I want to add a back button in Ionic4(Angular 7).
But I can't find the proper method in Angular Router.

`import {Router} from '@angular/router';`

How do we go back when clicking a button, in the component handler?
I'd like to implement it using '@angular/router' not '@angular/common' => Location

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5 - Which should I use to navigate backward - href or location.back()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51984177/angular-5-which-should-i-use-to-navigate-backward-href-or-location-back)

Comment: I want to go back without using Location, just with @angular/router.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using ionic 4 then to go backward, you can do the following:

```
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {}

btnClick(){
this.navCtrl.navigateBack('/home'); 
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to use `location.back()` from `@angular/common` when OP is using angular routing? (see https://angular.io/api/common/Location)

Comment: It is being called when u use`navigateBack()`, ionic uses it in there code

Comment: I just realized that when you use `location.back()` directly you don't get a proper back animation.

Answer (score 5):

With Angular routing you could use the Location API:

```
constructor(private location: Location){}
```

and then when you need to navigate back call:

```
this.location.back();
```

Keep in mind that for Angular 7 you have to import Location from `@angular/common`

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following if you wanna go back to your previous route.

```
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {}

goBack(){
 this.navCtrl.pop(); 
}
```

This'll pop the current page from the navigation stack and return you to the previous page and the part of the page from where you had navigated forward.