# Angular 7 Router - is there a way to pop the top route?

Tags: angular, router, angular7, angular-router

I have a bootstrap-modal in my application, and would like to be reflected on the browsing history when it's open, so when the user clicks the browser's back button - the modal will close.

I'm familiar with Angular's `Location` object, so `Location.back()` and `Location.go()` [works fine for my scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page).

The thing is - once the user clicked the back button, I would like to pop the top path from the browser history, so after closing the modal - the user couldn't reopen it using the browser's "next" button.

Any way to achieve this with Angular's [Router](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) / [Location](https://angular.io/api/common/Location) / any other Angular-ish way?

Comment: I was able to achieve this in my current project. let me find the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to achieve this. Whenever user clicks on the header component button called 'Post It', it displays a modal dialog. When user clicks the back button, it takes the user to the previous route. Here is my service that handles the opening of the dialog:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { PostItDialog } from './post-it-dialog.component';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';`

    public openPostItDialog(dialog: MatDialog): void {
        const dialogRef = dialog.open(PostItDialog, {
          width: '350px'
        });
        const url = this.router.createUrlTree(['posts/new']).toString();
        this.location.go(url);
        console.log("Dialog was open");
    
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
          console.log("The dialog was closed");
          this.location.go("");
        })
```

Comment: `afterClosed` will add another "empty" route, so when the user press the back one more time, It will go back to `posts/new`

Comment: Mine works as expected. i go from '/login' => '/' => '/posts/new'  then I hit back I go to '/' then i hit back again I go to '/login'. Have you actually tried this locally to see the behavior?

Comment: I did. my scenario is:

1. user click to open modal. route goes: `/page => /page(modal)`
2. user click to close modal. route goes: `/page(modal)  => /page`

So now routing stack is: `/page => /page(modal) => /page`
and when the user clicks back - it goes back to the modal route.
Moreover, I would like to prevent the user from going forward once the browser's "back" button clicked. I'm starting to doubt it can be achieved with JavaScript.