# How to redirected the user to the same page he came from?

Tags: angular

I have a page that I can access it from to two diff pages , and in this page, I have a button [BACK] and I want to redirect the user back to the page he comes from, can anyone give any tips.
Back
Thanks

Comment: You can get the help of given [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page) . There are many ways to implement back button. `window.history.back();` , use `Location` builtin service , etc.

Comment: Thanks also for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use angular `Location` package `back` method, it ll redirect the user to the previous page.

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

constructor(
   private location: Location
  ) { }

  goBack() {
    this.location.back();
  }
```

Comment: well done! I just want to have the opportunity  to do other question.