# I need to use the browser button to go back to the previous dynamic page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For example:
I'm on this page,
ciphxs? model = XS% 20Max & screen = 6.5 & color = 1 & capacity = 64GB

Clicking to go back I go to this page

ciphxs? model = XS% 20Max & screen = 6.5 & color = 1

Then clicking again would return to that page

ciphxs? model = XS% 20Max & screen = 6.5

I have a button that does this behavior, but I would use the browser button.

I am currently using typescript, but it would be nice to use JS even for the solution.

This is the div to back to the earlier page.

```
back() {
    this.capacity = null;
    this.canOrder = true;
    this.accepted = false;
    this.canOrderSubsidized = true;
    $(".final_selector").fadeOut(300)
    $(".capacity_selector").delay(300).fadeIn(300)
    $(".backCapacity").fadeOut(300)
    $(".backColor").delay(300).fadeIn(300)
  }
```

The div makes the result, but i want to make with the browser back button.

Comment: You can try out, ```window.history.back();``` or ```window.history.go(-1);```

Comment: I've to create a function to use that ?

Comment: Add any one line from above, at the bottom of the function.

Comment: If you are using Angular, then I would suggest use routes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, read [Angular official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router) first. Then you'll be able to use Angular Router and define each needed route (url).

Back navigation will be possible with below code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  //...
})
class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private location: Location) {}

  back() {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

As mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page).

Answer (score 0):

call the back function again on click og back button of browser.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   this.back();
}
```