# How to return to the previous page with angular?

Tags: angular

I want to return to the previous page where i were before the actual page.How to set that ?

i tried putting urls but how to know the previous one?

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col"><a href="#" class="hi-arrow-round-left">Back 
        </a>
        </div>
 </div>
```

i'm expeting when clicking on "Back" to go to the previous page but i'm getting home page caused by "#" because i'don't know how to get the previous page !

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52735465/479619

Comment: You've tagged this as Angular, but only shown HTML. If it is Angular, then the Angular documentation has this covered: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to go back last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **Location.back** like this:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

  constructor(private location: Location) {
  }

  goBack() {
    this.location.back();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add function to the a tag:

```
<a href="#" class="hi-arrow-round-left" onclick="goBack()">Back </a>
```

The function is:

```
<script>
function goBack() {
  window.history.back();
}
</script>
```