# Component Communication | Back and Forward Browser Buttons | Restore history.state payload

Tags: angular, navigation, components, state, history

**Problem**

On placing payload-data in the history to hand it over to another component, the data is lost on using the browser's Back and Forward buttons.

I implemented my own solution to restore previous payload-data.

**My solution**

```js
// some.component.ts
//
// navigate and set payload in arbitrary component

this.router.navigate(['/course/create'], {
  state: { payload: cid }
});
```

```js
// app.component.ts
//
// restore payload on using Back and Forward buttons

private historyStateCache = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {

      // SAVE CURRENT HISTORY

      const state = JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state  || {})
       );
      this.historyStateCache[event.id] = state;

      // PROCESS BACK AND FORWARD BUTTONS

      if (event.restoredState) {
        const targetId = event.restoredState.navigationId;  
        this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state = this.historyStateCache[targetId];

        // SAVE CURRENT HISTORY

        const stateX = JSON.parse(
          JSON.stringify(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state)
        );
        this.historyStateCache[event.id] = stateX;

      }
    }
}
```

**Question**

I am unsure if this is the 'correct" Angular way? I am new to Angular and the solution feels more like a hack.

Comment: Angular does not provide browser history.... so to get it, we have to do hack.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page

Answer (score 0):

By the powers of Stackoverflow granted to me, I hereby declare my above solution as the answer, as this way of hacking seems to be justified with Angular 8.