# How to get previous route in angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am trying to get the previous route path in Angular, But I don't know how to do that.

I know we can get the previous page location using

```
   this.location.back();
```

But I don't know how to get the route path like:

```
   /dashboard
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to go back last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page)