# Angular: how to only go back if inside application

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Going back to the previous page in Angular is [fairly simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  // component's declarations here
})
class SomeComponent {

  constructor(private _location: Location) 
  {}

  backClicked() {
    this._location.back();
  }
}
```

This is the equivalent of hitting your browser's "back" button. But how can this code be modified such that if `this._location.back()` is going to take you to a url *outside* of the app, that it instead redirects you to a route inside the app.

For example, say you're at `Google.com` and then you paste in `my-app.com/page-foo` and navigate that way. `this._location.back()` will take you back to `Google.com`, but I want it to instead navigate to `my-app.com/page-bar`.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#usage-notes), in your case you should use **router.navigate** method

Comment: Does that have a way of going `back` though?

Comment: you have to provide the url to which navigation should be done. usually this url is known, if it's not generic solution and you call it in component on some user's action

Comment: Right but the primary action that I want is to go `back`. With `location.back()` you don't need to know the url to use it. If I want to use `router.navigate` as you said, I would need some way of knowing what the previous url was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer at https://nils-mehlhorn.de/posts/angular-navigate-back-previous-page.

**1.** Make  a new `navigation-service`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavigationService {
  private MAX_HISTORY_LEN = 10; // prevent history from growing indefinitely
  private history: string[] = [];

  constructor(private router: Router, private location: Location) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.history.push(event.urlAfterRedirects);
        if (this.history.length > this.MAX_HISTORY_LEN) {
          this.history.shift();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  back(): void {
    this.history.pop();
    if (this.history.length > 0) {
      this.location.back();
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
    }
  }
}
```

**2.** Inject the service into `app.component.ts` so that it tracks history throughout the application

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService) {
  }
  ...
```

**3.** Then update the `(click)` function wherever you want to use this. Using the original example:

```
@Component({
  // component's declarations here
})
class SomeComponent {

  constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService) 
  {}

  backClicked() {
    this.navigationService.back();
  }
}
```

I made a few adjustments from the blogpost:

- Added a `MAX_HISTORY_LEN` to prevent the history array from growing indefinitely throughout app use
- Injected the `navigation-service` in `app.component.ts` so that it's always tracking history. If you only inject the service in the component that's calling `.back()` then it might not have a history the first time you call it.