# No back button when routing to a page within a separate tab (single-page app)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm building a mobile app using Ionic (which uses the Angular router). The app has a [tab bar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs) along the bottom, which is fairly standard.

Let's say my app structure looks something like this:

- Home - /tabs/home
- List of events - /tabs/events/list

  - View event - /tabs/events/view
  - Create event - /tabs/events/create

The event list contains links to the view-event screen which passes the clicked event in. It also has a link to the create-event screen.

My view-event and create-event pages have the following in the header, to take you back to the view-events screen.

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-back-button routerLink="/tabs/events/list" routerDirection="back"></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
```

On the homepage, I'd like to put a link to the Create Event page. If I add in `<ion-button routerLink="/tabs/events/create">Create Event</ion-button>` it changes the tab to the Events tab and shows me that page, but there's no Back button to return to the main Events List screen.

I've tried changing `<ion-back-button` to just `<ion-button` without any joy either.

Comment: Not sure will it work or not but try `Location`. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/36470719/5909026

Comment: Do you test in browser or mobile?

Comment: @SergeyMell both; where possible I test in browser with `ionic serve` as it's much faster, then go to `ionic cap run ios -l --external` to test on the device before pushing the code, or if any plugins are required

Comment: And the behavior of the back button is the same on web and mobile devices?

Comment: @SergeyMell yes. Looking at `defaultHref` as you mentioned in your deleted answer, that looks like it may do the trick. Do you know what the difference between that and `routerLink` is?

Comment: Yeah, that was smth I was thinking of, but it seems that the behavior is not correct. I'll do some more research a bit later today and maybe provide some more correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I've researched your question a little bit. In a general situation, `ion-back-button` won't be rendered if no history is available in your navigation stack.

However `ion-back-button` in conjunction with ion tabs works incorrectly. Here you can find the [explanation of this problem](https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tabs-back-button#problem-explained) which is confirmed by multiple issues: [Issue 1](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/15216), [Issue 2](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/17282) etc.

The first solution that could be used is [an enhanced ion-button package](https://github.com/servrox/demo-ionic-tabs-back-button). I didn't give it a try, but developers mention it in issues like a possible solution

An alternative way is to use `defaultHref` property which allows you to navigate back to the defined URL even if there is no history. This looks like a crutch in general way however may work in some simple cases when the back button URL is unambiguously predefined. See more about it here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button#properties

Comment: Cheers for the explanation, as well as potential workarounds. Much appreciated, have a great day!