# How to reach to previous to previous component in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose ,I have three routes  `A->B->C`  ,I go to B from A ,and then to C from B

Now  I want to move to A directly From C. Is this possible ?

Comment: Please include more details and clarify the problem especially a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `Location` Class in `angular/common` .
It has method [historyGo()](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#historyGo)

Example if you want to go to previous to previous component

```
 import {
    Location
} from "@angular/common"
class A {
    constructor(private location: Location) {}
    goBackTo() {
        this.historyGo(-1)

    }

}
```

As per docs

> Position of the target page in the history relative to the current
> page. A negative value moves backwards, a positive value moves
> forwards, e.g. location.historyGo(2) moves forward two pages and
> location.historyGo(-2) moves back two pages

Also you can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446955/how-to-go-back-last-page)