# Making a button to go back page

Tags: angular, api, angular-routing, angular15

I'm making an agular app which load data from an API, and when I go to another route and go back to table route the data is not there.

Is there some way to change route and not losing data?

```
<button [routerLink]="['/home']">
   <i class="bx bx-left-arrow-alt" id="icone"></i>
</button>
```

Now I'm just using a routerLink to change routes.

And I'm using angular 15.

Comment: Same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35446955/8784762) a few years ago but it has some fresh answers. you can check it

Comment: Have you tried Resolver? please insert your component ts file here

Comment: No, How it works?

Comment: I've seen this question but it didn't keep the data in table

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({selector: 'app-second-part',
templateUrl: './second-part.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./second-part.component.css']})
class SecondPartComponent {

 constructor(private location: Location){}

 goBack() {
  this.location.back();
 }
}
```

Comment: this way helps you if you want to keep your query params data.

Answer (score 0):

this is a resolver file

```
export class ReadyLinesResolver implements Resolve<any> { 

 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
   // return your API response
 }  
}
```

this is your router:

```
{
   path: '',
   resolve: {userInfo: UserInfoResolver},
},
```

you must inject the Router module in the constructor.

this is your ngOnInit component:

```
this.router.data.subscribe(res=> {
  // check here and find your property name
})
```

return your data in a variable and use them